# Power transmitted from Arbitrary Waveform Generator

Tags: power, rf, measurement, generator, spectrum-analyzer

I have an arbitrary waveform generator. The arbitrary waveform has 2x CW tones of same amplitude. I'm only able to configure the overall power of this waveform, and the generator's manual says this power level is "RMS Level" with unit in dBm.

My question is what's the definition of "RMS power"? If I follow the definition of RMS, then it should be defined as
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{T}p^{2}(t)dt}$$
where `p(t)` is the instantaneous power and `T` is the waveform's duration? I've only heard people speak about RMS voltage or current before. Or is it the average power defined as
$$\frac{1}{T}\int_{T}p(t)dt$$
Or is it the total power over the waveform duration `T` defined as
$$\int_{T}p(t)dt$$

I saw some other posts regarding power measured by spectrum analyzers but they all focus on freqency domain. I'm interested in a time domain explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit dBm is relative to 1mW. That is, 0dBm=1mW, +10dBm=10mW, +20dBm=100mW, +30dBm=1W, −30dBm=1μW, and so on. The formula is:

$$ P_{[dBm]} = 10log\left(\frac{P_{[W]}}{1mW}\right) $$

$$P_{[W]} = 1mW \times 10^{\left(\frac{P_{dBm}}{10}\right)}  $$

The power value quoted by your function generator is assuming that the load receiving power is 50Ω, and that the output impedance of the function generator itself is also 50Ω, so you have the situation on the left here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faGVDb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the right, the function generator is unloaded, and clearly the voltage signal at OUT will have (two times) greater amplitude (\$V_{OUT}=V_S\$, in fact), which I will address in a moment. For now, focus on the power being delivered to load RL, on the left.

As I said, the power value quoted by the function generator, which I will call \$P_L\$, is the average power in RL.

The internal signal (prior to source resistance RS) from your function generator \$V_S\$ is composed of two superimposed sinusoids of amplitudes \$A_1\$  and \$A_2\$. The formula for power in RL, as a function of the amplitudes of those sinusoids will be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_L &= \frac{1}{8R_L}({A_1}^2 + {A_2}^2) \\ \\
{A_1}^2 + {A_2}^2 &= 8P_LR_L
\end{aligned}
$$

A time-domain derivation for this is below, if it interests you. If both sinusoids have the same amplitude, such that \$A_1 = A_2 = A\$, then this becomes:

$$
\begin{aligned}
2A^2 &= 8P_LR_L \\ \\
A &= 2\sqrt{P_LR_L} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Let's suppose your function generator says that it will produce a superposition of two equal amplitude sinusoids, which together would deliver a power of 25dBm into a 50Ω load. First convert that to Watts:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_L &= 1mW \times 10^{\left(\frac{25dBm}{10}\right)} \\ \\
&= 316mW \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Then the amplitude \$A\$ of the two sinusoids will be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= 2\sqrt{P_LR_L} \\ \\
&= 2\sqrt{316mW \times 50\Omega} \\ \\
&= 7.95V
\end{aligned}
$$

This corresponds to \$V_S\$, the generator's internal voltage source, and doesn't account for its internal source impedance of 50Ω, or the load's impedance of 50Ω. If the load RL were absent, this is the sinusoid amplitudes you would see at node OUT.

With the load RL of 50Ω present, the sinusoids of \$V_{OUT}\$ will have half that amplitude, due to the resistor potential divider formed by RS and RL. That is, the contribution of each sinusoid to the total voltage \$V_{RL}\$ across RL will be of amplitude \$\frac{7.95V}{2}=3.975V\$.

According to the principle of superposition, each individual sinusoid can be treated as an independent power source, and the total power delivered to RL will be the sum of powers delivered by each individual sinusoid. Since we are dealing with sinusoids, we can simplify matters by working with RMS values, instead of amplitudes.

Considering that each contributing sinusoid across RL will have an amplitude of \$V_{PEAK}=3.975V\$, this corresponds to an RMS voltage of:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{RMS} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \times V_{PEAK} \\ \\
&= 2.811V \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The RMS power contribution (that is, average power over many cycles) from such a signal is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{RMS} &= \frac{{V_{RMS}}^2}{R_L} \\ \\
&= \frac{(2.811V)^2}{50\Omega} \\ \\
&= 158mW
\end{aligned}
$$

We have two such sinusoidal power sources, each delivering 158mW to the load, for a total of:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{TOTAL} &= 2 \times P_{RMS} \\ \\
&= 2 \times 158mW \\ \\
&= 316mW
\end{aligned}
$$

---

One possible derivation goes as follows. Since instantaneous power is \$P(t)=\frac{V^2(t)}{R}\$, then average power \$P_L\$ delivered to RL over some long interval \$T\$ is:

$$ P_L = \frac{1}{T}\int_{t=0}^T{\frac{{V_{OUT}}^2(t)}{R_L} \cdot dt} $$

\$V_{OUT}\$ is a copy of \$V_S\$, the source signal, attenuated by a factor of two by the potential divider RS and RL, so:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= \frac{1}{2}V_S \\ \\
P_L &= \frac{1}{T}\int_{t=0}^T{\frac{({\frac{1}{2}V_S})^2}{R_L} \cdot dt} \\ \\
P_L &= \frac{1}{4T R_L}\int_{t=0}^T{{V_S}^2 \cdot dt} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The source signal is a superposition of two sinusoids of frequencies \$\omega_1\$ and \$\omega_2\$, and amplitudes \$A_1\$ and \$A_2\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_S &= A_1 sin(\omega_1 t) + A_2 sin(\omega_2 t) \\ \\
{V_S}^2 &= {A_1}^2 sin^2(\omega_1 t) + {A_2}^2 sin^2(\omega_2 t) + 2A_1A_2 sin(\omega_1 t)sin(\omega_2 t) \\ \\
{V_S}^2 &= {A_1}^2 sin^2(\omega_1 t) + {A_2}^2 sin^2(\omega_2 t) + A_1A_2 cos\left[(\omega_1-\omega_2)t\right] - A_1A_2 cos\left[(\omega_1+\omega_2)t\right]\\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now integrate to find *average* power:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_L &= \frac{1}{4T R_L}\int_{t=0}^T{{V_S}^2 \cdot dt} \\ \\
&= \frac{{A_1}^2}{4T R_L}\int_{t=0}^T{sin^2(\omega_1 t) \cdot dt} + \frac{{A_2}^2}{4T R_L}\int_{t=0}^T{sin^2(\omega_2 t) \cdot dt} \\
& \dots + \frac{A_1A_2}{4T R_L}\int_{t=0}^T{\overbrace{cos\left[(\omega_1-\omega_2)t\right]}^\text{periodic with zero mean} \cdot dt} \\
& \dots - \frac{A_1A_2}{4T R_L}\int_{t=0}^T{\overbrace{cos\left[(\omega_1+\omega_2)t\right]}^\text{periodic with zero mean} \cdot dt} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The last two integral terms are periodic, and have a mean value of zero over each cycle. Therefore, as \$T\$ increases to many cycles, these terms go to zero, contributing no net power to the total. We are left with:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_L &= \frac{{A_1}^2}{4 R_L} \cdot \frac{1}{T}\int_{t=0}^T{sin^2(\omega_1 t) \cdot dt} + \frac{{A_2}^2}{4 R_L}\cdot \frac{1}{T}\int_{t=0}^T{sin^2(\omega_2 t) \cdot dt} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

At this point it is interesting to note that each individual sinusoid is clearly contributing power in the ratio \$\frac{{A_1}^2}{{A_2}^2}\$, the ratio of the square of amplitudes, in keeping with the principle of superposition. Continuing, though, each integral for the mean has the form:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{T}\int_{t=0}^T{sin^2(\omega t) \cdot dt} &= \frac{1}{T}\left[ \vphantom{\frac{}{}} \frac{t}{2}-\frac{sin(2\omega t)}{4t} \right]_0^T \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{T} \left( \frac{T}{2} - \frac{sin(2\omega T)}{4T} \right) \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{sin(2\omega T)}{4T^2} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Over a long period (many, many cycles), the mean value of the square of a sinusoid is then:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}{\left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{sin(2\omega T)}{4T^2}\right)} = \frac{1}{2} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Plugging this result into our expression for \$P_L\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_L &= \frac{{A_1}^2}{4 R_L} \cdot \frac{1}{T}\int_{t=0}^T{sin^2(\omega_1 t) \cdot dt} + \frac{{A_2}^2}{4 R_L}\cdot \frac{1}{T}\int_{t=0}^T{sin^2(\omega_2 t) \cdot dt} \\ \\
&= \frac{{A_1}^2}{4 R_L} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{{A_2}^2}{4 R_L} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{8R_L}({A_1}^2 + {A_2}^2) \\ \\
{A_1}^2 + {A_2}^2 &= 8P_LR_L
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what's the definition of "RMS power"?

There is no rms power. Power is the flow of energy in watts. Any source, advertising, marketing or anywhere else that uses the phrase "rms power" must be considered carefully.

> If I follow the definition of RMS,

It applies to voltage and current only in electronics.

\$V_{rms}\$ is the dc voltage that produces the same heating in a resistor as the time varying voltage. The same is true for \$I_{rms}\$

> manual says this power level is "RMS Level"

It is probably refering to rms voltage. If not then it is wrong.